# Passing non-const char array to function as const char array is possible?

Tags: c++, c

I was working with the `strcmp` function in C, then  i saw the function as arguments gets:

```
strcmp(_const char *s1, const char *s2)_;
```

And actually i passed normal char array and it worked. Any ideas why this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to use `const` key word to a pointer:

```
int my_int = 3;
const int* pt = &my_int;  //prevent to modify the value that pointer pt points to
int* const ps = &my_int;  //prevent to modify the value of pointer ps:
//it means the pointer is a const pointer, you can't modify the value of the pointer
//The value of the pointer ps is a memory address, so you can't change the memory address
//It means you can't reallocate the pointer(point the pointer to another variable)
int new_int = 5;
*pt = &new_int; //valid
*pt = 10; //invalid
*ps = &new_int; //invalid
*ps = 10; //valid
```

In `strcmp` function, the two arguments are pointer points to a const value, it means when you pass two char arrays or char pointers to the `strcmp` function, the function can use the value of those two pointers point to, but the function can't modify the value that you pass to it. That's why it works.

The `const` reference works in a similar way.

Comment: The asterisks shouldnt be present in `*pt = &new_int;` and `*ps = &new_int;`

Answer (score 4):

If you have for example the following code

```
char c = 'A';

char *p = &c;
const char *cp = &c;
```

then it means that you can change variable `c` using pointer `p` but you may not change it using pointer `cp`

For example

```
*p = 'B'; // valid assignment
*cp = 'B'; // compilation error
```

Thus function declaration

```
int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);
```

means that inside the function the strings pointed to by s1 and s2 will not be changed.

Answer (score 2):

This worked, because passing non-const in place of const is allowed. It is the other way around that is prohibited:

```
char *hello = new char[20];
char *world= new char[20];
strcpy(hello, "hello");
strcpy(world, "world");
if (!strcmp(hello, world)) {
    ...
}
```

The `const` in the declaration is meant to tell the users of the API that the function will not modify the content of the string. In C++ this is important, because string literals are `const`. Without the `const` in the API, this call would have been prohibited:

```
if (!strcmp(someString, "expected")) { // <<== This would not compile without const
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you intend to ask the mechanism of how the variable can compare the array.
if that's the case,

The pointer that has been declared in your example stores the initial address of the array's first element and
the ending point of the string can be determined by the detection null character that which in turn is the ending address of the array.

With that said the strcmp when called the pointer points to the strings or the character  passed that is, the command would be assumed as follows strcmp("string1","string2");
and thus the comparison takes place as usual.

hmm i guess by this and with other examples posted around you can get a better picture for your answer.